# How to add control variable in regression using statsmodels and sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to perform multiple linear regression using statsmodels and sklearn while controlling for covariates like socioeconomic status (age, gender, ethnicities). 
I have done it in SPSS which is fairly easy, since I can just click on the variables that I would like to control, but I have to switch to python, and don't know if there are any functions that allow me to do this?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you're trying to figure out how to code a multivariate regression?

You'd want to do:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
results = smf.ols('y ~ x1 + age', data=df).fit()
print(results.summary())
```

This would regress y onto your x1 and age.

If you want to include things like gender or ethnicity, then you'd need to introduce dummy variables.  Statsmodels can do that quickly by writing C() around your dummy variables.  This makes the variable a category variable (and remember that the first ethnicity or gender in your data will be the omitted variable).

```
results_2 = smf.ols('y ~ x1 + age + C(ethnicity) + C(gender)', data=df).fit()
print(results_2.summary())
```

Hope that helps.